# At most two values for the length of the roots in an irreducible root system

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

According to the following wikipedia page 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system,

> given an irreducible root system, there can be at most two values for the length of the roots.

Because of this, the terms **long** and **short** roots make sense. Since the root systems are classified, we can check this case by case. But this does not seem to be a good way to prove the above statement.

Is there a more fundamental explanation for this phenomenon? If so, where can I find such proof?

Comment: You can find a proof of this statement in Humphreys’ [*Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*, §10.4, Lemma C (page 53)](https://books.google.de/books?id=TeMlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22Then+at+most+two+root+lengths+occur%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfitiZh-vYAhWBCuwKHavvAkwQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22Then%20at%20most%20two%20root%20lengths%20occur%22&f=false)