# What is a simple component of a root system?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams

[image]

The above is from Knapp's *Lie Groups; Beyond an introduction'*, 2ed, page 397.

**Question 1:** What is a *simple component of a [reduced root system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#Definition)*? Or, more specifically, given a root system $\Delta$ and orthogonal roots $\alpha, \beta$ with $\alpha \pm \beta \in \Delta$, what is the *simple component of the root system containing $\alpha$ and $\beta$*?

These terms don't seem to appear in the index of Knapp, and don't seem to appear on Google either. I glanced back at the classification theory of root systems/Cartan matrices/Dynkin diagrams and couldn't get anything

**Question 2:** Why can't a *simple component of a reduced root system* have more than two root lengths?

This bound on number of root lengths doesn't seem to hold for root systems of dimension $\geq 3$? But it does seem to be true for two-dimensional root systems?

Blease help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** Here Knapp means [*irreducible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system) component of a root system. As for modules, people sometimes use *simple* and *irreducible* as a synonym.

**Question 2:** This is a well-known fact, see for example this duplicate:

[At most two values for the length of the roots in an irreducible root system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615781/at-most-two-values-for-the-length-of-the-roots-in-an-irreducible-root-system)

Comment: You should wear a cape.

Comment: Say, do you understand the comment about Dynkin diagrams in the screenshot? I thought vertices in Dynkin diagrams come from simple roots. Without loss of generality, we can assume $\alpha$ is simple (because it is a reduced root). But, in order to get the double line, is Knapp also assuming that one of $\alpha \pm \beta$ is part of the same simple system as $\alpha$?