# Which Dynkin diagram is being spoken about here? Why is there a double line?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams

I'm confused about the following comment in Knapp's *Lie Groups* 2ed, page 397. Here, $\Delta$ is a root system associated to a complex semisimple Lie algebra, $\alpha, \beta$ are orthogonal roots and we also have that $\alpha \pm \beta \in \Delta$ (that is, they are not strongly orthogonal).
[image]

[I believe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464633/what-is-a-simple-component-of-a-root-system) that the phrase *simple component* here means irreducible component. Since $\alpha \pm \beta$ are roots, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must lie in the same irreducible component of $\Delta$. Further, since $\Delta$ comes from a semisimple Lie algebra, this irreducible component is a reduced root system (and hence the comment about only two root lengths).

**Question:** What set of [simple roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#Positive_roots_and_simple_roots) within (an irreducible component of) $\Delta$ is the author using to obtain the Cartan matrix/Dynkin diagram with double line?

**Attempt:** I'm guessing there might be a way to show the existence of a simple system $\Pi \subset \Delta$ containing both $\alpha$ and $\beta - \alpha$. This would show that
\begin{equation}
2\frac{(\alpha, \beta -\alpha)}{|\alpha|^2} \cdot 2 \frac{(\alpha, \beta-\alpha)}{|\beta-\alpha|^2} = 2,
\end{equation}
thereby giving the double line. But I don't see how to construct this $\Pi$.

For example, if someone can provide a proof/reference showing that one can choose a simple system containing both $\alpha$ and $\beta - \alpha$, I will be happy.

Comment: Yes they mean irreducible component. The reason for the double line is that the ratio of short root length to long root length is $\sqrt{2}$ is it was $\sqrt{3}$ it would be a triple line. The precise set of simple roots doesn't matter they are all conjugate.

Comment: Er, but first, in any fixed simple system of roots, why is it true that there exists both a short and long root? For example, is it true that there exists a simple system containing both $\alpha$ and $\alpha + \beta$?

Comment: That is not true because of course we have root systems of type A, D and E which only have 1 root length. The key assumption here is that there are roots which are orthogonal but not strongly orthogonal. The result is thus that this can only happen when the roots are of different lengths with ratio $\sqrt{2}$. In particular we must be a root system of type B, C or F.

Comment: You're saying I should use the full classification theorem? :(    I guess I could but I wonder if there's a simpler way to see the presence of the double line?

Comment: No I'm just giving examples. The way to see the double line is the ratio of the lengths - that's exactly what the double line means

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow your comment 'that's exactly what the double line means.' When I looked at the bottom of page 159 in Knapp's book, the association from root system to Dynkin diagram follows by (1) choosing a set of simple roots $\{\alpha_i: i =1 ,\dots, n\}$ (2) creating a graph with $n$ vertices, each vertex having weight $|\alpha_i|^2$  and joining vertices $i, j$ with $2\frac{(\alpha_i, \alpha_j)}{|\alpha_i|^2} \cdot 2 \frac{(\alpha_j, \alpha_i)}{|\alpha_j|^2}$ edges. Is this the same correspondence/association you had in mind?

Comment: If so, my question is, what choice of simple roots establishes the existence of two edges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136885/discussion-between-united-agrarian-peasant-party-and-callum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put my comments into a proper answer:

We can see that the number of lines between two nodes in the diagram is given by $$N := \langle\alpha_i, \alpha_j\rangle\langle\alpha_j, \alpha_i\rangle = 2\frac{(\alpha_i, \alpha_j)}{|\alpha_i|^2} \cdot 2 \frac{(\alpha_j, \alpha_i)}{|\alpha_j|^2} = 4\frac{(\alpha_i, \alpha_j)^2}{|\alpha_i|^2|\alpha_j|^2} = 4 cos^2 (\theta).$$
Where $\theta$ is the angle between them. Since we have $ \langle\alpha_i, \alpha_j\rangle,\langle\alpha_j, \alpha_i\rangle,N $ all integers and from the above they are between $-3$ and $3$ ($N$ is also positive) there are only a few possibilities.
Additionally we have (as long as $\alpha_i, \alpha_j$ are not orthogonal):
$$ \frac{\langle\alpha_i, \alpha_j\rangle}{\langle\alpha_j, \alpha_i\rangle} = \frac{|\alpha_i|^2}{|\alpha_j|^2}.$$

Comparing the possibilities, it is clear that $\frac{|\alpha_i|^2}{|\alpha_j|^2}$ is in fact equal to $N$ whenever $N$ is non-zero (assuming $\alpha_i$ is the longer root). So now we just need the fact that if there are two roots somewhere in our system with $\frac{|\alpha_i|^2}{|\alpha_j|^2} = 2$ then there are two non orthogonal simple roots (in any choice of simple roots) with the same ratio of lengths.

In fact it should be clear that a set of simple roots should automatically have at least one root of each length so we just need a pair that are non-orthogonal. But this is also immediate since the Dynkin diagram is connected and we have only two lengths present: At some point between our two originally chosen nodes we must have a transition from long to short.